# Uploading Image to AWS S3 bucket from localhost working but not working for the same application deployed In Elastic Beanstalk with IAM

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, upload

I have deployed a Java Web Application in AWS Beanstalk. One of the functionality of my application is to upload Image to the AWS S3 bucket. I have created an IAM user which is assigned to the EC2 instance launched by Elastic Beanstalk. Now while I am trying to upload an image from the deployed application the image is not getting uploaded in the Bucket which has a public access level. Though the same piece of code is working while I am uploading the same Image from the same application running at my Localhost. I have checked the logs also but didnt get any clue .

Any type of help or guide to debug the issue will be appreciated.

Sharing my catalina.out log below

```
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.416 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/trains/layout]}" onto public java.lang.String com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.TrainController.getTrainPartialPage(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.422 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/admin/delete/{articleID}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public boolean com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.AdminPanelController.deleteArticle(int)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.425 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/admin/getAllArticles],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.AdminPanelController.getAllArticles()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.426 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/admin/update],methods=[PUT]}" onto public boolean com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.AdminPanelController.updateArticle(com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.426 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/admin/fileupload],methods=[POST]}" onto public javax.xml.crypto.Data com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.AdminPanelController.continueFileUpload(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.426 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/admin/add],methods=[POST]}" onto public boolean com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.AdminPanelController.addNewArticle(com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.427 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/admin/layout]}" onto public java.lang.String com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.AdminPanelController.getCarPartialPage()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.436 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/home/lattestArticles],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.HomePageController.getLattestArticles()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.438 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/home/articles],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.HomePageController.getAllArticles()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.439 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/home/languageCustom],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.HomePageController.getLaguageAndCustomArticle()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.439 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/home/editorials],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.HomePageController.getEditorialsArticle()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.440 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/home/layout]}" onto public java.lang.String com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.HomePageController.getCarPartialPage()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.440 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/home/memorable],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.HomePageController.getMemorablePersosArticles()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.441 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/home/popular],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.HomePageController.getPopularArticles()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.444 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/login/layout]}" onto public java.lang.String com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.LoginController.getCarPartialPage()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.445 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/login/authentication/{username}/{password}],methods=[GET]}" onto public boolean com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.LoginController.authenticate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.446 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/language/Alllanguage],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.LanguageAndCultureController.getAllMemorablePersonArticle()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.453 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/language/layout]}" onto public java.lang.String com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.LanguageAndCultureController.getCarPartialPage()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.537 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
15-Nov-2018 20:15:26.549 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler]
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.189 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Nov 15 20:15:23 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.513 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4165 ms
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.583 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.587 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Nov 15 20:15:27 UTC 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.593 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions Registering annotated classes: [class com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.config.WebMvcConfig]
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.750 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.<init> JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.766 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName Loaded JDBC driver: org.postgresql.Driver
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.835 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/ourvoice/AllOurVoice],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.OurVoiceController.getEditorialsArticle()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.835 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/ourvoice/layout]}" onto public java.lang.String com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.OurVoiceController.getCarPartialPage()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.836 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.IndexController.getIndexPage()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.839 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/railwaystations/add],methods=[POST]}" onto public void com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.RailwayStationController.addRailwayStation(com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.RailwayStation)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.840 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/railwaystations/update],methods=[PUT]}" onto public void com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.RailwayStationController.updateRailwayStation(com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.RailwayStation)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.840 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/railwaystations/railwaystationlist.json]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.RailwayStation> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.RailwayStationController.getRailwayStationList()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.841 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/railwaystations/remove/{id}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.RailwayStationController.removeRailwayStation(java.lang.Long)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.841 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/railwaystations/removeAll],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.RailwayStationController.removeAllRailwayStations()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.842 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/railwaystations/layout]}" onto public java.lang.String com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.RailwayStationController.getRailwayStationPartialPage(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.843 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/details/popular],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.ArticleDetailsController.getAllArticles()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.849 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/details/newsDetails/{articleID}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.ArticleDetailsController.getAllArticles(int)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.850 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/details/layout]}" onto public java.lang.String com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.ArticleDetailsController.getCarPartialPage()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.850 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/memorable/Allmemorable],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.MemorablePersonController.getAllMemorablePersonArticle()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.853 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/memorable/layout]}" onto public java.lang.String com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.MemorablePersonController.getCarPartialPage()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.854 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/editorial/Alleditorials],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.EditorialController.getEditorialsArticle()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.854 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/editorial/layout]}" onto public java.lang.String com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.EditorialController.getCarPartialPage()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.856 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/trains/addTrain],methods=[POST]}" onto public void com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.TrainController.addTrain(com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.Train)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.857 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/trains/updateTrain],methods=[PUT]}" onto public void com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.TrainController.updateTrain(com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.Train)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.858 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/trains/trainslist.json]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.Train> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.TrainController.getTrainList()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.858 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/trains/removeTrain/{id}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.TrainController.removeTrain(java.lang.Long)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.858 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/trains/removeAllTrains],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public void com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.TrainController.removeAllTrains()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.859 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/trains/layout]}" onto public java.lang.String com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.TrainController.getTrainPartialPage(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.867 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/admin/delete/{articleID}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public boolean com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.AdminPanelController.deleteArticle(int)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.867 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/admin/getAllArticles],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.AdminPanelController.getAllArticles()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.868 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/admin/update],methods=[PUT]}" onto public boolean com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.AdminPanelController.updateArticle(com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.869 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/admin/fileupload],methods=[POST]}" onto public javax.xml.crypto.Data com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.AdminPanelController.continueFileUpload(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.869 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/admin/add],methods=[POST]}" onto public boolean com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.AdminPanelController.addNewArticle(com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.869 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/admin/layout]}" onto public java.lang.String com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.AdminPanelController.getCarPartialPage()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.872 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/home/lattestArticles],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.HomePageController.getLattestArticles()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.872 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/home/articles],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.HomePageController.getAllArticles()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.876 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/home/languageCustom],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.HomePageController.getLaguageAndCustomArticle()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.877 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/home/editorials],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.HomePageController.getEditorialsArticle()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.877 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/home/layout]}" onto public java.lang.String com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.HomePageController.getCarPartialPage()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.877 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/home/memorable],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.HomePageController.getMemorablePersosArticles()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.878 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/home/popular],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.HomePageController.getPopularArticles()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.879 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/login/layout]}" onto public java.lang.String com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.LoginController.getCarPartialPage()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.879 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/login/authentication/{username}/{password}],methods=[GET]}" onto public boolean com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.LoginController.authenticate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.880 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/language/Alllanguage],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.beans.ArticleDetails> com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.LanguageAndCultureController.getAllMemorablePersonArticle()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.881 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/language/layout]}" onto public java.lang.String com.xvitcoder.springmvcangularjs.controller.LanguageAndCultureController.getCarPartialPage()
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.892 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.893 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler]
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.909 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Nov 15 20:15:27 UTC 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
15-Nov-2018 20:15:27.989 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 406 ms
15-Nov-2018 20:15:28.015 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [9,854] ms
15-Nov-2018 20:15:28.019 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
15-Nov-2018 20:15:28.049 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
15-Nov-2018 20:15:28.056 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 9971 ms
Get Lattest  Articles
Get Lattest  Articles
Inside Dao Implementation
Get Lattest  Articles
Get Lattest  Articles
Get Lattest  Articles
Inside Controller Method
Inside Controller Method
Inside Service Method
recievwd all the articles:19
Inside add API Controller
article idnull
Inside Controller Method
Inside Service Method
recievwd all the articles:20
Before Authentication
After Authentication
Not Uploaded
Inside add API Controller
article idnull
Inside Controller Method
Inside Service Method
recievwd all the articles:21
Before Authentication
After Authentication
Not Uploaded
```

Comment: AWS should return an exception message on a failed put. What do the logs say?

Comment: Getting permission denied Error message from the log... Now let me tell what are the steps I have followed for EC2 Instance . I have created a role with policy to fully access to AWS S3 and attached the role with an IAM user and attached the user with EC2 Instance ... I am very new to AWS and followed some tutorials  available in the Internet.

Comment: Check out this AWS doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html to grant permission which elastic beanstalk will pass on to the EC2 instance